# Подключение констант из заголовочного файла

Tags: c++, linux, c, файлы, компиляция

Имеется заголовочный файл *Constants.h*, в котором определены константы.
`SS_INF_ROOTS` используется в `main`. Тип `Bool` используется в `main` и в другом заголовочном файле *Functions.h*, в котором определены прототипы функций, а также в файлах *.с*, в которых содержатся функции.

*Constants.h*:

```c
#ifndef Functions_h
#define Functions_h

const int SS_INF_ROOTS = -1;

typedef enum Bool {
    FALSE,
    TRUE
} Bool;

#endif
```

Файл *Functions.h* с прототипами функций:

```c
#ifndef Functions_h
#define Functions_h

double checkDoubleOverflow(double d1, double d2, int x);

void nCheckDouble (double a, double b, double c,
                double *x1, double *x2);

Bool EqualZero (double d);

void LinSolve (double a, double b, double *x1);

int SquareSolve (double a, double b, double c,
                     double *x1, double *x2);
            
#endif
```

Далее происходит ошибка `идентификатор "Bool" не определен`.
Как надо подключить заголовочный файл *Constans.h*, чтобы константы и типы объявленных в днем данных работали в файлах *.с*, где хранятся функции и в другом заголовочном файле *Functions.h*? Компилятор gcc.

Comment: Для начала, объявляйте нормальный #ifndef, после чего включайте заголовочный файл там где нужно #include

Comment: Ну тау у вас же одинаковый guard - `#ifndef Functions_h`, так что после включения `Functions.h` ваш `Constants.h` уже попросту не читается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для ускорения компиляции больших проектов хедеры разделены по частям. Какая-то часть пользуется одним, какая-то другим. В хедерах присутсвует блокировка повторной обработки с помощью макросов. Без этой блокировке могут быть ошибки повторного объявления структур.

Ошибка первая : макросы у разных файлов должны быть разными.

Ошибка вторая : в предварительном объявлении функций не подключили объявление типа Bool.

Ошибка третья : объявление переменных не должны быть в хедерах. При компиляции второго файла будет конфликт, что переменная ещё одна появилась с таким-же именем.

Вот рабочий пример самой растянутой реализации :

type.h :

```
#ifndef Type_h
#define Type_h

typedef enum Bool Bool;

#endif
```

constants.h :

```
#ifndef Constants_h
#define Constants_h

extern  const int SS_INF_ROOTS ;

enum Bool {
    FALSE,
    TRUE
} ;

#endif
```

functions.h :

```
#ifndef Functions_h
#define Functions_h

double checkDoubleOverflow(double d1, double d2, int x);

void nCheckDouble (double a, double b, double c,
                double *x1, double *x2);

# include "type.h"

Bool EqualZero (double d);

void LinSolve (double a, double b, double *x1);

int SquareSolve (double a, double b, double c,
                     double *x1, double *x2);
            
#endif
```

const.c :

```
# include "constants.h"
const int SS_INF_ROOTS = -1;
```

main.c :

```
# include "constants.h"
# include "functions.h"

int main(){
  int i = SS_INF_ROOTS ;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но почему мы создаем отдельный файл const.c для объявления SS_INF_ROOTS, а потом передаем эту переменную в заголовочный файл constants.h. Почему мы также не объявляем перечисление в отдельном файле, а сразу делаем это в .h.

Comment: Облазил весь гугл, но так и не нашел структурированного руководства про разбиение программы на файлы, можете что-то подсказать?

Comment: enum - это объявление типа без обеспечения места памяти в программе. Разрешается делать это второй раз. А переменная обеспечивает место в коде. А extern - это предварительное объявление переменной без выделения места.

Comment: А почему бы сразу в Type.h не объявить enum полностью? Почему мы делаем typedef в Type.h, потом в constants/h определяем enum? Почему также для typedef не требуется extern. Ведь у нас определение типа размазано по заголовочным файлам.

Comment: type.h предназначен для предварительного объявления типа, без уточнения какие значения он содержит. При добавлении новых констант не будет причин перекомпилировать весь проект. Предварительно объявить тип второй раз можно. А переменную только с extern.

Comment: Почему мы в в constants.h пишем extern const int SS_INF_ROOTS, а потом в const.c только присваиваем ей значение?

Comment: Также когда мы делаем  файл с функцией, то ничего, что мы и там подключаем библиотеки, которые в main? Просто получается, что мы постоянно дублируем подключаемые библиотеки.

Comment: `extern` предварительно объявляет переменную, можно тыщу раз это делать. А самой переменной задать константное значение только один раз. Когда вы делаете include библиотеку, то получаете обещание, что указатель на функцию найдут при сборке. Типа extern указателя на функцию получаете при include. А при сборке компилятор добавляет свои откомпилированные `.so` с этими функциями.